# QVideoFilterRunnable causes Segmentation Fault with PySide2

Tags: python, qml, pyside2, qvideofilterrunnable

I am attempting to show a video feed while processing the image with OpenCV. I already have a script that does the image processing using OpenCV and Python, but attempting to add any filter to the `VideoOutput` results in a segmentation fault. The [documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QAbstractVideoFilter.html) only has examples for C++, but I have tried to replicate it exactly in Python.

Here is my Python file (example.py):

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import qmlRegisterType
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QAbstractVideoFilter, QVideoFilterRunnable
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl

class ExampleFilterRunnable(QVideoFilterRunnable):
    def run(self, frame, surfaceFormat, flags):
        return frame

class ExampleFilter(QAbstractVideoFilter):
    def createFilterRunnable(self):
        return ExampleFilterRunnable()


app = QApplication([])
qmlRegisterType(ExampleFilter, "ExampleFilter", 1, 0, "ExampleFilter")
view = QQuickView()
url = QUrl("example.qml")

view.setSource(url)
view.setResizeMode(view.SizeRootObjectToView)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

And the QML (example.qml):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtMultimedia 5.8
import ExampleFilter 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "black"

    ExampleFilter {
        id: filter
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: player
        source: "https://archive.org/download/Mario1_500/Mario1_500_LQ.avi"
        autoPlay: true
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        source: player
        filters: [filter]
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

I added debug output to try to understand what was happening, as no errors are printed beside "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". The segmentation fault occurs sometime after the `ExampleFilterRunnable` is instantiated in `createFilterRunnable` and before `ExampleFilterRunnable::run` is called.

I have run it on different computers with different video cards, and with different types of videos and camera feeds, and the result is the same. If I comment out the `filters: [filter]` line in `VideoOutput`, the video plays.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this might actually be a bug in PySide2: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-785